# Serializing PHP object to JSON

Tags: php, object, json, object-serialization

So I was wandering around [php.net](http://php.net) for information about serializing PHP objects to JSON, when I stumbled across the new [JsonSerializable Interface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php). It's only **PHP >= 5.4** though, and I'm running in a 5.3.x environment.

How is this sort of functionality achieved **PHP < 5.4**?

I've not worked much with JSON yet, but I'm trying to support an API layer in an application, and dumping the data object (*that would otherwise be sent to the view*) into JSON would be perfect.

If I attempt to serialize the object directly, it returns an empty JSON string; which is because I assume `json_encode()` doesn't know what the heck to do with the object. Should I recursively reduce the object into an array, and then encode *that*?

---

## Example

```
$data = new Mf_Data();
$data->foo->bar['hello'] = 'world';
```

**`echo json_encode($data)`** produces an empty object:

```
{}
```

**`var_dump($data)`** however, works as expected:

```
object(Mf_Data)#1 (5) {
  ["_values":"Mf_Data":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_children":"Mf_Data":private]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["foo"]=>
      object(Mf_Data)#2 (5) {
        ["_values":"Mf_Data":private]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["_children":"Mf_Data":private]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          array(1) {
            ["bar"]=>
            object(Mf_Data)#3 (5) {
              ["_values":"Mf_Data":private]=>
              array(1) {
                [0]=>
                array(1) {
                  ["hello"]=>
                  string(5) "world"
                }
              }
              ["_children":"Mf_Data":private]=>
              array(0) {
              }
              ["_parent":"Mf_Data":private]=>
              *RECURSION*
              ["_key":"Mf_Data":private]=>
              string(3) "bar"
              ["_index":"Mf_Data":private]=>
              int(0)
            }
          }
        }
        ["_parent":"Mf_Data":private]=>
        *RECURSION*
        ["_key":"Mf_Data":private]=>
        string(3) "foo"
        ["_index":"Mf_Data":private]=>
        int(0)
      }
    }
  }
  ["_parent":"Mf_Data":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_key":"Mf_Data":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_index":"Mf_Data":private]=>
  int(0)
}
```

---

## Addendum

### 1)

So this is the `toArray()` function I've devised for the `Mf_Data` class:

```
public function toArray()
{
    $array = (array) $this;
    array_walk_recursive($array, function (&$property) {
        if ($property instanceof Mf_Data) {
            $property = $property->toArray();
        }
    });
    return $array;
}
```

However since the `Mf_Data` objects also have a reference to their parent (*containing*) object, this fails with recursion. Works like a charm though when I remove the `_parent` reference.

### 2)

Just to follow up, the final function to transform a complex tree-node object I went with was:

```
// class name - Mf_Data
// exlcuded properties - $_parent, $_index
public function toArray()
{
    $array = get_object_vars($this);
    unset($array['_parent'], $array['_index']);
    array_walk_recursive($array, function (&$property) {
        if (is_object($property) && method_exists($property, 'toArray')) {
            $property = $property->toArray();
        }
    });
    return $array;
}
```

### 3)

I'm following up again, with a bit cleaner of an implementation. Using interfaces for an `instanceof` check seems much cleaner than `method_exists()` (*however `method_exists()` does cross-cut inheritance/implementation*).

Using `unset()` seemed a bit messy too, and it seems that logic should be refactored into another method. However, this implementation *does* copy the property array (*due to `array_diff_key`*), so something to consider.

```
interface ToMapInterface
{

    function toMap();

    function getToMapProperties();

}

class Node implements ToMapInterface
{

    private $index;
    private $parent;
    private $values = array();

    public function toMap()
    {
        $array = $this->getToMapProperties();
        array_walk_recursive($array, function (&$value) {
            if ($value instanceof ToMapInterface) {
                $value = $value->toMap();
            }
        });
        return $array;
    }

    public function getToMapProperties()
    {
        return array_diff_key(get_object_vars($this), array_flip(array(
            'index', 'parent'
        )));
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 Nice question, didn't know this feature yet.

Comment: @takeshin - Yeop, edit date on the doc page is 4 days ago. I'm glad to see it!

Comment: For reference to others looking at this, json_encode can handle objects just fine. However, it only encodes public-members of that object. So if you have protected or private class variables, then you need either one of the posted methods, or JsonSerializable.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Certainly. Old question is old now, and < 5.4 isn't really an option anymore anyway (or at least shouldn't be) Definitely `JsonSerializable`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

---

**edit**: it's currently 2016-09-24, and PHP 5.4 has been released 2012-03-01, and support has *ended* 2015-09-01. Still, this answer seems to gain upvotes. If you're still using PHP < 5.4, *your are creating a security risk and endagering your project*. If you have no compelling reasons to stay at <5.4, or even already use version >= 5.4, **do not use this answer**, and just use PHP>= 5.4 (or, you know, a recent one) and implement [the JsonSerializable interface](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php#class.jsonserializable)

---

You would define a function, for instance named `getJsonData();`, which would return either an array, `stdClass` object, or some other object with visible parameters rather then private/protected ones, and do a `json_encode($data->getJsonData());`. In essence, implement the function from 5.4, but call it by hand.

Something like this would work, as `get_object_vars()` is called from inside the class, having access to private/protected variables:

```
function getJsonData(){
    $var = get_object_vars($this);
    foreach ($var as &$value) {
        if (is_object($value) && method_exists($value,'getJsonData')) {
            $value = $value->getJsonData();
        }
    }
    return $var;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Wrikken - Is there any shortcut for reducing an object, objects contained therein (*all members regardless of visibility or type*) to an associative array, or typecasting it to `stdClass`? I'm thinking in the direction of *Reflection*, but if not, I'll just figure out something to recursively perform it.

Comment: Reflection would be the long way. As you are _inside_ the class in your `getJsonData()` function, you could just call `get_object_vars()`, and loop through that result looking for more objects.

Comment: I've nearly gotten it sorted out; the issue now is recursion. Each object has a `_parent` property so the tree can be traversed to the root. See my edit for an update; perhaps I should ask another question as this issue is now abstracted from my original.

Comment: A simple `unset($array['_parent']);` before the walk should do the trick.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @Wrikken - I was starting to try complicated equality tests, passing a context object `$parent` as user-data to `array_walk_recursive()`. Simple is beautiful! Also, its `$array["\0class\0property"]` because of null-byte pollution because I was using casting. I think I'll switch to `get_object_vars()`.

Answer (score 95):

In the simplest cases type hinting should work:

```
$json = json_encode( (array)$object );
```

Comment: This gives long winded/ugly property names if you work with namespaces and auto loader.

Comment: is there a way to get cleaner property names?

Comment: why does it adds \u0000*\u0000 in the start of prop names?

Comment: Useless with private properties. You all should learn about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle.

Answer (score 21):

`json_encode()` will only encode public member variables. so if you want to include the private once you have to do it by yourself (as the others suggested)

Answer (score 12):

Following code is doing the job using reflection. It assumes you have getters for the properties you want to serialize

```
    <?php

    /**
     * Serialize a simple PHP object into json
     * Should be used for POPO that has getter methods for the relevant properties to serialize
     * A property can be simple or by itself another POPO object
     *
     * Class CleanJsonSerializer
     */
    class CleanJsonSerializer {

    /**
     * Local cache of a property getters per class - optimize reflection code if the same object appears several times
     * @var array
     */
    private $classPropertyGetters = array();

    /**
     * @param mixed $object
     * @return string|false
     */
    public function serialize($object)
    {
        return json_encode($this->serializeInternal($object));
    }

    /**
     * @param $object
     * @return array
     */
    private function serializeInternal($object)
    {
        if (is_array($object)) {
            $result = $this->serializeArray($object);
        } elseif (is_object($object)) {
            $result = $this->serializeObject($object);
        } else {
            $result = $object;
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @param $object
     * @return \ReflectionClass
     */
    private function getClassPropertyGetters($object)
    {
        $className = get_class($object);
        if (!isset($this->classPropertyGetters[$className])) {
            $reflector = new \ReflectionClass($className);
            $properties = $reflector->getProperties();
            $getters = array();
            foreach ($properties as $property)
            {
                $name = $property->getName();
                $getter = "get" . ucfirst($name);
                try {
                    $reflector->getMethod($getter);
                    $getters[$name] = $getter;
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    // if no getter for a specific property - ignore it
                }
            }
            $this->classPropertyGetters[$className] = $getters;
        }
        return $this->classPropertyGetters[$className];
    }

    /**
     * @param $object
     * @return array
     */
    private function serializeObject($object) {
        $properties = $this->getClassPropertyGetters($object);
        $data = array();
        foreach ($properties as $name => $property)
        {
            $data[$name] = $this->serializeInternal($object->$property());
        }
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * @param $array
     * @return array
     */
    private function serializeArray($array)
    {
        $result = array();
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            $result[$key] = $this->serializeInternal($value);
        }
        return $result;
    }  
}
```

Comment: this is a great Class !  it also works with protected object items.

Answer (score 7):

Just implement an Interface given by PHP [JsonSerializable](http://php.net/manual/de/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php).

Answer (score 2):

Since your object type is custom, I would tend to agree with your solution - break it down into smaller segments using an encoding method (like JSON or serializing the content), and on the other end have corresponding code to re-construct the object.

Answer (score 2):

My version:

```
json_encode(self::toArray($ob))
```

Implementation:

```
private static function toArray($object) {
    $reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($object);

    $properties = $reflectionClass->getProperties();

    $array = [];
    foreach ($properties as $property) {
        $property->setAccessible(true);
        $value = $property->getValue($object);
        if (is_object($value)) {
            $array[$property->getName()] = self::toArray($value);
        } else {
            $array[$property->getName()] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

JsonUtils : [GitHub](https://github.com/primosz67/tahona-spark-mvc/blob/master/src/spark/utils/JsonUtils.php)

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Solves problem with privates. Simple and small.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this, this worked fine for me.

```
json_encode(unserialize(serialize($array)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to your variable types `private` to `public`

This is simple and more readable.

For example

**Not Working;**

```
class A{
   private $var1="valuevar1";
   private $var2="valuevar2";
   public function tojson(){
    return json_encode($this)
   }
}
```

**It is Working;**

```
class A{
   public $var1="valuevar1";
   public $var2="valuevar2";
   public function tojson(){
    return json_encode($this)
   }
}
```

Comment: its very odd. but its true.

Answer (score 0):

I made a nice helper class which converts an object with get methods to an array.
It doesn't rely on properties, just methods.

So i have a the following review object which contain two methods:

**Review**

- getAmountReviews : int
- getReviews : array of comments

**Comment**

- getSubject
- getDescription

The script I wrote will transform it into an array with properties what looks like this:

```
    {
      amount_reviews: 21,
      reviews: [
        {
          subject: "In een woord top 1!",
          description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque laoreet lacus quis eros venenatis, sed tincidunt mi rhoncus. Aliquam ut pharetra diam, nec lobortis dolor."
        },
        {
          subject: "En een zwembad 2!",
          description: "Maecenas et aliquet mi, a interdum mauris. Donec in egestas sem. Sed feugiat commodo maximus. Pellentesque porta consectetur commodo. Duis at finibus urna."
        },
        {
          subject: "In een woord top 3!",
          description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque laoreet lacus quis eros venenatis, sed tincidunt mi rhoncus. Aliquam ut pharetra diam, nec lobortis dolor."
        },
        {
          subject: "En een zwembad 4!",
          description: "Maecenas et aliquet mi, a interdum mauris. Donec in egestas sem. Sed feugiat commodo maximus. Pellentesque porta consectetur commodo. Duis at finibus urna."
       },
       {
          subject: "In een woord top 5!",
          description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque laoreet lacus quis eros venenatis, sed tincidunt mi rhoncus. Aliquam ut pharetra diam, nec lobortis dolor."
    }
]}
```

Source: [PHP Serializer which converts an object to an array that can be encoded to JSON.](https://github.com/Jamiek94/PHPSerializeObjectToArray)

All you have to do is wrap json_encode around the output.

**Some information about the script:**

- Only methods which starts with get are added
- Private methods are ignored
- Constructor is ignored
- Capital characters in the method name will be replaced with an underscore and lowercased character

Answer (score -7):

I spent some hours on the same problem.
My object to convert contains many others whose definitions I'm not supposed to touch (API), so I've came up with a solution which could be slow I guess, but I'm using it for development purposes.

This one converts any object to array

```
function objToArr($o) {
$s = '<?php
class base {
    public static function __set_state($array) {
        return $array;
    }
}
function __autoload($class) {
    eval("class $class extends base {}");
}
$a = '.var_export($o,true).';
var_export($a);
';
$f = './tmp_'.uniqid().'.php';
file_put_contents($f,$s);
chmod($f,0755);
$r = eval('return '.shell_exec('php -f '.$f).';');
unlink($f);
return $r;
}
```

This converts any object to stdClass

```
class base {
    public static function __set_state($array) {
        return (object)$array;
    }
}
function objToStd($o) {
$s = '<?php
class base {
    public static function __set_state($array) {
        $o = new self;
        foreach($array as $k => $v) $o->$k = $v;
        return $o;
    }
}
function __autoload($class) {
    eval("class $class extends base {}");
}
$a = '.var_export($o,true).';
var_export($a);
';
$f = './tmp_'.uniqid().'.php';
file_put_contents($f,$s);
chmod($f,0755);
$r = eval('return '.shell_exec('php -f '.$f).';');
unlink($f);
return $r;
}
```

Comment: There is another fine and accurately answer, already accepted. Does your answer adds something radically different, more efficient or compact? I guess not

Comment: I'm going to be honest; I don't think this answers the question, at all.

Comment: It's been about 6 months; I've periodically returned here due to upvotes, and to make some edits for future visitors; I **still** have no idea what the hell this is supposed to do.

Comment: `unlink($thisAnswer);`

Comment: people tend to downvote what they don't understand. It might not be per say an exact solution but it is something to look into. In such case you ask for clarifications before downvotes.

Comment: `inline php strings`, `eval`, `shell_exec(php)`... c-c-combo.