# Convert Doctrine 2 result object (entity) to array?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I know that it is possible to specify that you want array type instead of object type when you run query with Doctrine. However, I happen to be working with the code that I can't edit which returns to me the result from a query as an object and I want to be able to convert that to array somehow. It seems like in the older version doctrine used to have something like `toArray()` which can be used.

Is there something similar to that now which I can use?

Comment: Take a look to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836592/serializing-php-object-to-json

Answer (score 3):

No, doctrine 2 uses the data mapper pattern and doesn't make any assumptions about the PHP class. If the class doesn't provide a toArray() method explicitly, then you'd need to create the array manually with the object's getter methods.