# Laravel : How to store json format data in database?

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I want to store some json format data in database from a given array. But How i do store it using controller.

Suppose I have json data like :

```
{"id":"bangladesh","divisions":[{"name":"Barisal"},{"name":"Chittagong"},{"name":"Dhaka"},{"name":"Khulna"},{"name":"Rajshahi"},{"name":"Rangpur"},{"name":"Sylhet"}]}
```

So far as I know in controller using json format is like this as I'm not fully aware of it.

```
public function saveUser(Request $request)
{
    $div=new Div();
    $user->json = json_encode( array({"Date 1": {
        {"id":"bangladesh","divisions":[{"name":"Barisal"},{"name":"Chittagong"},{"name":"Dhaka"},{"name":"Khulna"},{"name":"Rajshahi"},{"name":"Rangpur"},{"name":"Sylhet"}]}   
    $div->save();    
    return redirect('getList');
}
```

How do i save it in mySQL only the list of divisions in Division Model using Laravel Controller?

Comment: You can use php serialize function

Comment: can you suggest me with sample code  please?

Comment: Check at this link for more:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836592/serializing-php-object-to-json

Answer (score 31):

You don't need to convert the array data to a JSON string yourself, use the Laravel $casts parameter on your model:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

You should do something like this in your Div model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'divisions' => 'array',
];
```

Comment: Just clarify something!

How do I set the `$options['key'] = 'value';`

Comment: Here array means prepare key value pair in array like array('key' =>'value')

Comment: thsi is the right answer for me..

Answer (score 6):

You can convert your Model to JSON format like
`$model->toJson();`

or

if you have data in an array you can use `json_encode(['id' => 1, 'name' => 'User 1']);`

Laravel Schema does support JSON field types as well look https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#adding-columns

You can use `text` field type as well to store JSON data.

Comment: Confirmed, I just converted a `<textarea>` Vue component to a rich text editor (vue-tiptap) and stored the JSON glyphs into the existing `notes` field that is text type: `$table->text('notes')->nullable();`. I'm just here searching out alternatives that could be better.

Answer (score 5):

Set your model

```
protected $casts = [
        'list' => 'array'
    ];
```

Here is the full code.

```
/**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'primary_id', 
        'list'
    ];


    protected $casts = [
        'list' => 'array'
    ];

    public function setMetaAttribute($value)
    {
        $list = [];

        foreach ($value as $array_item) {
            if (!is_null($array_item['key'])) {
                $list[] = $array_item;
            }
        }

        $this->attributes['list'] = json_encode($list);
    }
```