# How to store data into exists row

Tags: php, laravel

I write code for insert booking data into my database when inserting new data it will create new row so I'm getting duplicate data's so I need to store the data if schedules_id equal to exists schedules_id store the seat data into that table an array format, here how I did.

```
$booking = new Bookings();
        $booking->users_id = 4;
        $booking->schedules_id = $schedules_id;
        $booking->buses_id = $buses_id;
        $booking->routes_id = $routes_id;
        $booking->seat = implode(',', $seat);
        $booking->price = $request->price;
        $booking->profile = 'pending';
```

Comment: Do you want to store only `seat data` if `schedules_id` exists?

Comment: 1. what you want to match to update 2. do you have primary key here like `id` ?

Comment: @bhavinjr yeah sir

Comment: @NikleshRaut yeah bookings_id

Comment: Please read about [`firstOrNew`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent)

Comment: You need a relationship between bookings and seats. Do not store an "array" in a column.

Comment: @apokryfos sir, I have 50 seats for one bus so how can I store all the data in a separate row it will increase the data init?

Comment: @NikleshRaut ty so much sir!

Comment: Store in a separate table (e.g. named `booking_seats`) with structure like  `booking_id, seat` and you will only need to duplicate the booking_id for each seat associated with that booking. However the advantages of this greatly outweigh the disadvantage of duplicating an identifier. In this case `booking_id` is a foreign key referencing id on booking.

Comment: @apokryfos OK sir I will try that too ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `updateOrCreate` method on your model, so try this:

```
$booking = Bookings::updateOrCreate(
    ['schedules_id' => $schedules_id, 'users_id' => 4 ], // match the row based on this array
    [ // update this columns
        'buses_id' => $buses_id,
        'routes_id' => $routes_id,
        'seat' => json_encode($seat),
        'price' => $request->price,
        'profile' => 'pending',
    ]

);
```

Comment: sir i need to store a seat data in an array format JSON encode

Comment: Assuming your `$seat` is an array you don't need to use `implode` as that converts it to a string, you can directly use `json_encode` on the array, it will turn it into a string. Then the reverse would be `json_decode($seat, TRUE)` this returns array.

Comment: ty so much sir!

Comment: sir it is updating data, only one data will be stored in column

Comment: then you will need to display your previous data into the view before you update it with additional data. Or use another approach, where you first look for the item, if it exists then update the existing one adding the new fields, or create a new one if it does not exist.

Comment: prb is i need store all booked seat into one column in a array format, if schedules_id same i need to add another seat into that table after that i need to show all the booked seat into view so how can i do that sir?

Answer (score 0):

try this

Assume `Bookings` is Model

```
$matchThese = ['schedules_id' => $schedules_id];

Bookings::updateOrCreate($matchThese,[
    'seat'  => implode(',', $seat)
]);
```

or

```
$data = $request->all();

$data['seat'] = implode(',', $seat);

$matchThese = ['schedules_id' => $schedules_id];

Bookings::updateOrCreate($matchThese, $data);
```

Make sure you added columns in `$fillable` in Bookings model

You can make casting in your model

```
protected $casts    = [
        'seat'           =>  'array',
    ];
```

If you are using Array casting then `$data['seat']` should be array

Comment: sir i need to store a seat data in an array format JSON encode

Comment: ty so much sir!

Comment: getting error "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

Comment: Are you using array cast in model?

Comment: If you are using Array casting then `$data['seat']` should be array

Answer (score 0):

```
$booking = Bookings::firstOrCreate(
           ['schedules_id' => $schedules_id ],// row to test if schedule id matches existing schedule id
           [ // update this columns
              'buses_id' => $buses_id,
              'routes_id' => $routes_id,
              'seat' => implode(',', $seat),
              'price' => $request->price,
              'profile' => 'pending',
           ]);
```

You can use this firstORcreate laravel method. More description about its usage is given on this stackoverflow page.

[First Or Create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178464/first-or-create)

But if you want store the data as an array you can create text or json field in your database for the data and use eloquent serialization to work with it.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-serialization

Another stack overflow example where this question about storing data in json is answered is 
[Laravel : How to store json format data in database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37803214/laravel-how-to-store-json-format-data-in-database)

Comment: ty so much sir!