# Doctrine entity to different json views

Tags: serialization, doctrine-orm, lumen

When I get a list of entities from Doctrine, how can I return different json 'views' ?
Ie. when I load Student classes I want views with only `id, displayName` and another with more details `id, firstName, lastName, email, groups`. 
Groups is another collection with `id, name`. 
I'm using lumen and doctrine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serializing PHP object to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836592/serializing-php-object-to-json)

Comment: @goto I don't believe it is a duplicate. Your link provides information on serializing all fields. I just want to serialize some fields. And even more: I must be able to serialize two fields for request A, and 5 fields for request B.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement JsonSerializable interface on your entityes and create custom versions on it.
ie:

```
class MyEntity implements JsonSerializable {

  /**
   * Doctrine annotation 
   */
  private $myEntityMember;

  ...

  public function jsonSerialize() {
     //serialize your entity here and use custom params to modify the serialized object output
  }

}
```

This way you can call `$myEntityObject->jsonSerialize()` whenever you need.