# How can I get search results based on DuckDuckGo API?

Tags: php, json, duckduckgo-api

I want to decode json file resulted from [DuckDuckGo API](http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=DuckDuckGo&format=json&pretty=1) into a readeble html or PHP string.

I try with PHP `json_decode`, but nothing:

```
$object = json_decode($string, true);
echo $object['RelatedTopics']['Result'];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does `$string` actually contains what you expect?

Comment: Nope. `$string` contains all json resulted from [a simple searchusing DuckDuckGo API](http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=DuckDuckGo&format=json&pretty=1)

Comment: Don't you get any error?  http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: I get a notice. `Notice: Undefined index: Result in C:\...\default.php on line 257`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serializing PHP object to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836592/serializing-php-object-to-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the JSON responde you posted, it is possible to see that `RelatedTopics` is an array. So you must first access an element of this array to then access the `Result` key:

```
echo $object['RelatedTopics'][0]['Result'];
```

Or in a loop just to test:

```
foreach ($object['RelatedTopics'] as $rel)
    echo $rel['Result'];
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much.